# How can I capture multiple occurrances of a string within a matched group (nested regex)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to parse an XML file with (of course) nested structure:

```
<begin>
<Paket>
<Name>Kwertzu</Name>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Glubub</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Gwertzu</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Klu_gulbi</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>QWER_TZU_ewrt</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>MERM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
</Paket>
<Paket>
<Name>KULU</Name>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>GLM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>IWUS_asd</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
<Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>PLUM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
</Paket>
</begin>
```

I am interested in getting the names in  and all contents of  ...

I tried with: 
`r'<Paket>\s*<Name>(\w*)</Name>.*?(?:<Kurzbezeichnung>(.*?)</Kurzbezeichnung>.*?)*</Paket>', re.S`
That only returns the last entry in , though...
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried using an XML parser?  It would probably be better than a regex (as much as I love them!)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Actually I have tried that but I failed miserably in using it. In spite of reading a lot about the structure I was not able to extract the necessary tags from my XML. I have solved the problem with two nested regex searches (searching for the outer tags first and then search the matches for the inner tags. That works but I think it will be much slower than a combined search...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why the XML parsing was tough, took me a bit!  Here is a working example of what you want:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main ():
    data = '''<begin>
    <Paket>
    <Name>Kwertzu</Name>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Glubub</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Gwertzu</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Klu_gulbi</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>QWER_TZU_ewrt</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>MERM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    </Paket>
    <Paket>
    <Name>KULU</Name>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>GLM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>IWUS_asd</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>PLUM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
    </Paket>
    </begin>'''

    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    for child1 in root:
        for child2 in child1:
            if child2.tag == "Name":
                print (child2.text)
            if child2.tag == "Funktion":
                for child3 in child2:
                    if child3.tag == "Kurzbezeichnung":
                        print (child3.text)

main ()
```

This will output:

```
Kwertzu
Glubub
Gwertzu
Klu_gulbi
QWER_TZU_ewrt
MERM
KULU
GLM
IWUS_asd
PLUM
```

Basically making an object that you can iterate on.  The key points are:

using .tag --that's what the node is

using .text --that's the value in the node

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. As always my simplification of the example for posting here made the code not work in my setting and I had to extensively change it. Mainly the problem was the insidious namespaces...

Comment: cool.  If you did find my answer helpful though I would appreciate it being accepted :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. I am new here, so I didn't know I could/should do that. I even provided my solution that I managed to create using your example as a starting point. However, I am not allowed to post it due to "spam from my location" :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since my example was too simplified and the "real" XML looks more like this:

```
<MyList xmlns="http://www.example.com">
  <FirstTag>
    <Name>Group</Name>
    <SecondTag>
      <Name>DCT23335.7</Name>
      <ThirdTag>
        <Name>AnotherName</Name>
        <Paket>
            <Name>Kwertzu</Name>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Glubub</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Gwertzu</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>Klu_gulbi</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>QWER_TZU_ewrt</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>MERM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
        </Paket>
        <Paket>
            <Name>KULU</Name>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>GLM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>IWUS_asd</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
            <Funktion><Kurzbezeichnung>PLUM</Kurzbezeichnung><OtherTag>content</OtherTag></Funktion>
        </Paket>
      </ThirdTag>
    </SecondTag>
  </FirstTag>
</MyList>
```

Therefore you have to fight with namespaces and the crazy nested nature of XMLs by coding:

```
root = ET.fromstring(data)

ns = {'ns': re.findall(r'<MyList xmlns="([^"]*)"', data)[0]}
dict_elements = {}
outer_elements = root.find('ns:FirstTag', ns).find('ns:SecondTag', ns).find('ns:ThirdTag', ns).findall('ns:Paket', ns)

for outer_element in outer_elements:
    outer_element_name = outer_element.find('ns:Name', ns).text
    inner_elements = outer_element.findall('ns:Funktion', ns)
    for inner_element in inner_elements:
        dict_elements[inner_element.find('ns:Kurzbezeichnung', ns).text] = outer_element_name
```

This works but (even without the regex lookup of the namespace string) takes almost twice as long as the nested regex search I used before.
Seems like I am still not a fan of ElementTree...
Thanks again for helping me making at work at all!